# How can i add separate captions below illustrations?

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions

How can i add separate captions for each illustration. One caption for the left illustration and one caption for the right illustration. Both captions should be below the illustration.

The illustrations I am referring to are given in code below.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{Caption}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance = 3mm and 20mm,
        arr/.style = {draw=blue!70!black, -{Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}, very thick},
          N/.style = {font=\small, text width=60mm, align=center, inner sep=2pt},
                                ]
        % left image
        \node (n1) [N]  {Set \mbox{$r_1=0$}\\
                         Anvend fast vindue $[0,r_2]$};
        \draw[thick]    (n1.west) -- ++ (0,-24mm)
                        (n1.east) -- ++ (0,-24mm);
                        %
        \coordinate[below=19mm of n1.west] (aux1);
        \path[arr]  (n1.east |- aux1) node[right] {$r_2$} --
                    (aux1) node[left] {$r_2$};
        % right image
        \node (n2) [N, right=of n1]  
                        {Set \mbox{$r\in[0,r_1-r_2]$}\\
                         Anvend fast termineringsvindue $[r_1,r_2]$};
        \draw[thick]    (n2.west) -- ++ (0,-24mm)
                        (n2.east) -- ++ (0,-24mm);
                        %
        \coordinate[below=19mm of n2.west] (aux2);
        \coordinate[above=of aux2] (aux3);
        \coordinate[above=of aux3] (aux4);
        \path[arr]  (n2.east |- aux2) --
                    (aux2) node[left] {$r_1$};
        \path[arr]  (n2.east |- aux3) node[right] {$r_2$} -- ++ 
                    (-36mm,0) node[left] {$r_1$};
        \path[arr]  (n2.east |- aux4) -- node[above] {$r_w=r_2-r_1$} ++
                    (-24mm,0) node[left] {$r_1$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
    \caption*{(a) ADF test (b) BSADF test}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

One way is to split image to two image and each insert into `subfloat` environment:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\tikzset{
    node distance = 3mm,
    arr/.style = {draw=blue!70!black, -{Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}, very thick},
      N/.style = {font=\footnotesize, text width=54mm, align=center, inner sep=2pt},
        }
    \centering
\subfloat[ADF test]{%
% left image
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node (n1) [N]  {Set \mbox{$r_1=0$}\\
                 Anvend fast vindue $[0,r_2]$};
\draw[thick]    (n1.west) -- ++ (0,-24mm)
                (n1.east) -- ++ (0,-24mm);
                %
\coordinate[below=19mm of n1.west] (aux1);
\path[arr]  (n1.east |- aux1) node[right] {$r_2$} --
            (aux1) node[left] {$r_2$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
                }%
\hfill%
\subfloat[BSADF test]{%
% right image
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node (n2) [N]  {Set \mbox{$r\in[0,r_1-r_2]$}\\
                 Anvend fast termineringsvindue $[r_1,r_2]$};
\draw[thick]    (n2.west) -- ++ (0,-24mm)
                (n2.east) -- ++ (0,-24mm);
                %
\coordinate[below=19mm of n2.west] (aux2);
\coordinate[above=of aux2] (aux3);
\coordinate[above=of aux3] (aux4);
\path[arr]  (n2.east |- aux2) --
            (aux2) node[left] {$r_1$};
\path[arr]  (n2.east |- aux3) node[right] {$r_2$} -- ++
            (-36mm,0) node[left] {$r_1$};
\path[arr]  (n2.east |- aux4) -- node[above] {$r_w=r_2-r_1$} ++
            (-24mm,0) node[left] {$r_1$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
                }
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:my_label}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Addedndum:**
A rewuire OP:

[image]

With use of the `subfigure` defined in `subcaption` package:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\tikzset{
    node distance = 3mm,
    arr/.style = {draw=blue!70!black, -{Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}, very thick},
      N/.style = {font=\footnotesize, text width=54mm, align=center, inner sep=2pt},
        }
    \centering
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:my_label}
% left image
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\linewidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node (n1) [N]  {Set \mbox{$r_1=0$}\\
                 Anvend fast vindue $[0,r_2]$};
\draw[thick]    (n1.west) -- ++ (0,-24mm)
                (n1.east) -- ++ (0,-24mm);
                %
\coordinate[below=19mm of n1.west] (aux1);
\path[arr]  (n1.east |- aux1) node[right] {$r_2$} --
            (aux1) node[left] {$r_2$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{ADF test}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill%
% right image
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\linewidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node (n2) [N]  {Set \mbox{$r\in[0,r_1-r_2]$}\\
                 Anvend fast termineringsvindue $[r_1,r_2]$};
\draw[thick]    (n2.west) -- ++ (0,-24mm)
                (n2.east) -- ++ (0,-24mm);
                %
\coordinate[below=19mm of n2.west] (aux2);
\coordinate[above=of aux2] (aux3);
\coordinate[above=of aux3] (aux4);
\path[arr]  (n2.east |- aux2) --
            (aux2) node[left] {$r_1$};
\path[arr]  (n2.east |- aux3) node[right] {$r_2$} -- ++
            (-36mm,0) node[left] {$r_1$};
\path[arr]  (n2.east |- aux4) -- node[above] {$r_w=r_2-r_1$} ++
            (-24mm,0) node[left] {$r_1$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{BSADF test}
\end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. But the figure caption is now in the bottom, is it possible to have the figure caption in the top and still keep the sub captions in the bottom. I hope you understand me.

Comment: @Konstantin, you require unusual design. However, this is possible. See addendum in answer.